# Modal dialog is closing unexpectedly when i clicked a button to navigate to another tab in angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use tabs inside modal dialog where if i clicked on the next button it should navigate to another tab.But instead of navigating,the dialog closed unexpectedly.Could someone help me where actually i went wrong.

**Html**

```
<div>
    <h4 class="dialog-headline">Configure Device
        <span>
       <mat-icon class="pull-right close-icon" (click)="onCloseDialog()">close</mat-icon>
    </span></h4>

</div>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <mat-tab-group #matgroup>
        <mat-tab label="Details">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="content-container tab-content-height">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput formControlName="devicename" placeholder="Enter Device name">
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput formControlName="devicedesc" placeholder="Enter Device Description">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-dialog-actions class="pull-right">
                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)='matgroup.selectedIndex = 1'>Next</button>
                    </mat-dialog-actions>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Location">
            <div class="tab-content" style="height: 140px">

                <div class="content-container">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select placeholder="Select the store" formControlName="store">
                            <mat-option value="option"
                            *ngFor="let store of this.stores" [value]="store.name">{{store.name}}</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>

                <mat-dialog-actions>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
                            type="submit"
                            (click)="onCloseDialog()"
                            style="margin-left: 20px;">Save
                    </button>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)='matgroup.selectedIndex = 0'>Back</button>
                </mat-dialog-actions>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

    import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      templateUrl:'file-name-dialog.component.html',
      styleUrls:['file-name-dialog.component.css'
      ]

    })
    export class FileNameDialogComponent {

        form: FormGroup;
        stores;

        constructor(
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FileNameDialogComponent>,

        ) {}

        ngOnInit() {

            this.stores==['arun','reddy'];
            this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                devicename: '',
                devicedesc: '',
                store: ['']
            });
            this.form.patchValue({
                store: this.stores ? this.stores[0] : 'None'
            });
        }
        onCloseDialog() {
            this.dialogRef.close();
        }
        submit() {
          this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
        }
    }
```

Here is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-demo-reactiveforms?file=app/file-name-dialog.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `$event.preventDefault()` to the click handlers of your buttons.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialog-demo-reactiveforms-se3szi?file=app/file-name-dialog.component.html)

Comment: For me, `$event.stopPropagation()` was the solution but thanks for putting me in the right direction.